# Excel: Custom Ribbon template (XLSTART)

Tags: excel, templates, ribbon

I have created a **custom tab** for the Excel **ribbon** with a single group and a single button. This is **saved as an XLSM file** and when opening it works as supposed.

I would like this custom tab to **to appear whenever an excel document is opened**. The XLSM file is saved on the XLSTART folder and does launch when any excel document is opened. The issue is that 2 documents are opened, the XLSM with the custom tab and the clicked on file with the standard Ribbon only.

I guess this is normal since it's considered a separate file and not a template; but **if the file is saved as template** (tested both XLTX and XLTM) **Excel won't read it at all**.

- Double-clicking on the template does open it (the issue is to make it launch automatically)
- Issue appears only when the document in XLSTART is a template
- References in the template are written in the correct language
- Already tested on different machines
- I'm using Excel 2016 (32bit)

The idea is to provide this template to every user who needs the tool in the custom tab without having to create an installation executable file (blocked in our environment) and have it launch automatically with excel.

Have you encountered this issue or know something that I might have missed?

**CustomUi14.xml**

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onL`oad="OnRibbonLoad">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="tab0" label="NUEVOVI Tools">
        <group id="grp0" autoScale="true" centerVertically="false" label="Any365 Reports" getVisible ="GetVisible" tag = "RibbonName:=;inMenu:=;CustomTagValue1:=;CustomTagValue2:=;CustomTagValue3:=;CustomPicture:=;CustomPicturePath:=" >
          <button idMso="ChartInsert" showLabel="true" size="large" label="Generate" tag="RibbonName:=;inMenu:=;CustomTagValue1:=;CustomTagValue2:=;CustomTagValue3:=;CustomPicture:=;CustomPicturePath:=" onAction="generateReport" getVisible="GetVisible" getEnabled="GetEnabled" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

**.rels file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="R7f19f805bfb641b9" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2007/relationships/ui/extensibility"    Target="customUI/customUi14.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties" Target="docProps/app.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties" Target="docProps/core.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="xl/workbook.xml"/></Relationships>
```

File: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=76809226544239420467

Comment: show your xml file of ribbon

Comment: The xml data has been added. But the code works, the issue remain that Excel doesn't read template files from the XLSTART folder (other files on that folder work fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved by **saving the file as XLAM**. That made it work perfectly.
For some (for me unknown) reason template files do not get loaded from the XLSTART forlder.

Answer (score 0):

[Configuring Excel](http://www.meadinkent.co.uk/xlconfigure.htm)

and try this

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="OnRibbonLoad">
  <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
    <tabs>
      <tab id="tab0" label="NUEVOVI Tools" insertBeforeMso = "TabHome" keytip = "G">
        <group id="grp0" autoScale="true" centerVertically="false" label="Any365 Reports" getVisible ="GetVisible" tag = "RibbonName:=;inMenu:=;CustomTagValue1:=;CustomTagValue2:=;CustomTagValue3:=;CustomPicture:=;CustomPicturePath:=" >
          <button idMso="ChartInsert" showLabel="true" size="large" label="Generate" tag="RibbonName:=;inMenu:=;CustomTagValue1:=;CustomTagValue2:=;CustomTagValue3:=;CustomPicture:=;CustomPicturePath:=" onAction="generateReport" getVisible="GetVisible" getEnabled="GetEnabled" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

On some networks with a lot of security restrictions, you may not have access to the XLSTART directory or you may not have permission to save files. Instead, create a startup directory on your own system with any name you want and store the book.xltx file in this new alternate startup directory. The directory name you choose doesn’t matter, but you will need to tell Excel where it is.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. It did indeed move the tab to the first page but once saved as XLTM and placed on the XLSTART folder it didn't start up.
*The template does not appear on the Disabled Items either.

XLSM files get launched fine from XLSTART; XLTM do not at all.

Comment: so please attach your file

Comment: I just added the file. Bear in mind that it is the XLSM version. You will need to save it as XLTM on the XLSTART folder to experience the issue.